# Distinguish email addresses of a contact

Tags: android, email, contactscontract, android-contentresolver

I have 3 email's of the same contact. I need to update this emails to phone book of Android. The problem is that when I try do this, the 3 email's are updated the same way. The 3 email's stay equals. Exist any way to distinguish the emails?

Here is my code

```
if(numEmails>1){
     int auxNumEmails=1;
     String tagEtEmail = "ete";
     String tagBtnLabelEmail = "btnLabelMail";
     //Determinar o número de email do content
     do{
         EditText etEmail = (EditText)contentEmail.findViewWithTag(tagEtEmail);
         Button etBtnLabelEmail = (Button)contentEmail.findViewWithTag(tagBtnLabelEmail);
         String stEtEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
         String stBtnLabelEmail = etBtnLabelEmail.getText().toString();
         values.clear();

         String mailWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA+"=?"; 
         String[] mailWhereParams = new String[]{String.valueOf(idContacto),ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, "2"}; 
         values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,stEtEmail);

         if(stBtnLabelEmail == "Residência"){
         values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME);
         values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.LABEL,stBtnLabelEmail);
         }
         else
             if(stBtnLabelEmail == "Emprego"){
                 values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK);
                 values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.LABEL,stBtnLabelEmail);
             }
         **cr.update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values, mailWhere, mailWhereParams);**

     tagEtEmail = "ete"+auxNumEmails;
     tagBtnLabelEmail = "btnLabelMail" + auxNumEmails;
     auxNumEmails++;

     }while(auxNumEmails<=numEmails);
```

I need a way to distinguish the emails. Id? But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i use to distinguish diferent emails for the same contact is use the tag atribute. Each email have a diferent tag that allow distinguish each one.